# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push to heroku, and I am getting the following error:

[image]

Originally, this started out as an error saying "invalid css after @import bootstrap", but I added a semicolon after @import bootstrap and now it has changed to the NoMethodError. I think it has something to do with the asset pipeline, but it doesn't really give any description. The app runs just fine on localhost:3000 with no problems.

I am using postgresql database for both development and production.

I ran $ heroku logs and this is the result:

[image]

I am not using slugs in my app, so I don't know why it is giving the slug error. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I simply added config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false to my application.rb file under config/application.rb. The problem was heroku was pre compiling my assets for development mode.